# Python Accessing Dict That Has Defualt Values That Have Been Updated

Tags: python, dictionary, return-value

So I have this class:

```
class hero():

    def __init__(self, name="Jimmy", prof="Warrior", weapon="Sword"):
        """Constructor for hero"""
        self.name = name
        self.prof = prof
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.herodict = {
            "Name": self.name,
            "Class": self.prof,
            "Weapon": self.weapon
        }
        self.herotext = {
            "Welcome": "Greetings, hero. What is thine name? ",
            "AskClass": "A fine name, {Name}. What is your class? ",
            "AskWeapon": "A {Class}, hmm? What shalt thy weapon be? ",
        }

    def setHeroDicts(self, textkey, herokey):
        n = raw_input(self.herotext[textkey].format(**self.herodict))

        if n == "":
            n = self.herodict[herokey]

        self.herodict[herokey] = n
        #print self.herodict[herokey]

    def heroMake(self):
        h = hero()
        h.setHeroDicts("Welcome", "Name")
        h.setHeroDicts("AskClass", "Class")
        h.setHeroDicts("AskWeapon", "Weapon")
```

And in another class I have this executing

```
def Someclass(self):
    h = hero()
    print h.herodict["Class"]
    h.heroMake()
    print h.getClass()

    if "Mage" in h.herodict["Class"]:
        print "OMG MAGE"
    elif "Warrior" in h.herodict["Class"]:
        print "Warrior!"
    else:
        print "NONE"
```

So if I input nothing each time, it will result in a blank user input, and give the default values. But if I put an input, then it will change the `herodict` values to what I customize. My problem is, if I try and access those updated values in `Someclass` it only gives me the default values instead of the new ones. How do I go about accessing the updated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your class is that you are creating a new object within `heromake` instead of using the existing one.  You can fix this by replacing `h` with `self` (so that each time you are calling `setHeroDicts` on the object):

```
def heromake(self):
    self.setHeroDicts("Welcome", "Name")
    self.setHeroDicts("AskClass", "Class")
    self.setHeroDicts("AskWeapon", "Weapon")
```

The first argument to a method is always set to the instance itself, so if you want to interact with the instance or mutate it, you need to use it directly.  When you do `h = hero()` in your original code, you create a whole new `hero` object, manipulate it and then it disappears when control passes back to your function.

A few other notes: you should name your classes with CamelCase, so it's easier to tell they are classes (e.g., you should really have `class Hero`) and in python 2, you need to make your classes descend from object (so `class Hero(object)`). Finally, you are duplicating nearly the entire point of having classes with your `herodict`, you should consider accessing the attributes of the object directly, instead of having the intermediary `herodict` (e.g., instead of doing `h.herodict["Class"]` you could do `h.prof` directly.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I'll be reading it a few dozen times as it sinks in. I appreciate it!

Comment: About `e.g., instead of doing h.herodict["Class"] you could do h.prof directly.` if I do that it would return the default value, and not the updated dict though, or am I misunderstanding

Comment: @PaulDuncan Yes, that's true, if you didn't change your code at all, you'd end up with the default value. I'm suggesting that you use your class in place of `herodict` and set the attributes on your class itself.

Comment: Ahh I get what you mean. I was doing that originally but Im using dict mainly to learn how to manipulate and access them, as I plan on having a lot more entries that (i think) would be a good use for them.